# Optional edit in GridView's rows?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Suppose I have a GridView on the page. GridView has edit column enabled and is showing some records. How can I enable/disable edit in rows based on other fields of data?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want to disable/enable editing ability on a row based on data (i.e disable the 'Edit' LinkButton on a row if a field is equal to true)? Or, automatically put a row into edit mode based on the same the kind of condition?

Comment: @Jamie: I mean "want to disable/enable editing ability on a row based on data (i.e disable the 'Edit' LinkButton on a row if a field is equal to true)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a number of ways. Two of these are:

First convert the edit column to a template field.

Whatever field you want to base the enable/disable on you can add the the GridView's DataKeyNames property.

Then on the OnRowDataBound event you can do the following:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal)
    {
        var LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("LinkButton1");
        LinkButton1.Enabled = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value == "SomeValue"; //Or some other logic, like converting to a boolean
    }
}
```

Or,

In the Html markup of you aspx page, edit the linkbutton enabled property to bind the your desired field. Such as:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Edit" Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SomeField")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Hope that helps.